# Gridview Freeze Panes Jscript runtime error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, jscript

I'm sure you are tired of this error, but I can't work out what my problem is looking at other peoples similar issues. 
This is all to do with gridview freeze panes. I have a very basic web app that essentially shows a gridview (and also has custom paging functionality).

I have used this site to try to incorporate column freezing in my gridview for when you scroll across the page, using this site:
http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Demo.aspx

This is the error that I'm getting:
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

and it highlights the below code on error:

```
  function gridviewScroll() {
            $('#<%=gvOpportunity.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({

            });
        }
```

Here is my full code, excluding the gridview itself (otherwise this post will be huge):

```
    PageSize:
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPageSize" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="PageSize_Changed">
<asp:ListItem Text="10" Value="10" />
<asp:ListItem Text="25" Value="25" />
<asp:ListItem Text="50" Value="50" />
<asp:ListItem Text="100" Value="100" />
```

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvOpportunity" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display."
    OnRowUpdating="OnRowUpdating" OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="OnRowCancelingEdit" 
    BorderWidth="0px" CellSpacing="1" CellPadding="1" GridLines="Horizontal" >
        <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No." >
                <HeaderStyle Width="50px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemStyle Width="50px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbRowNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

           ...............more template fields...........................

        </Columns>

        <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridviewScrollC1Header" /> 
        <RowStyle CssClass="GridviewScrollC1Item" /> 

    </asp:GridView>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/gridviewScroll.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            gridviewScroll();
        });


        function gridviewScroll() {
            $('#<%=gvOpportunity.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({
                freesize: 2
            });
        } 
    </script>




    <asp:Repeater ID="rptPager" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Text") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Value") %>'
                Enabled='<%# Eval("Enabled") %>' OnClick="Page_Changed"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

</div>
```

I have no idea what to do next, and have tried to look for the same errors and have been unable to adapt the solution. I appreciate any help you can give here, please let me know if you need further info.

Comment: Bumping - no reply!

Answer (score 0):

I threw together my own minimal example and it worked. I used v0.9.6.8 from https://github.com/twlikol/GridViewScroll/blob/master/gridviewScroll.min.js

I have IE11 installed. Using the "document mode" dropdown to make it emulate older versions, I stepped back through the miserable history of IE and it kept working in all modes, except the sizing was off in mode 5.

You misspelled `freezesize` as `freesize` but that wouldn't cause a javascript error.

Page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:GridView ID="gvOpportunity" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No." >
                <HeaderStyle Width="150px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemStyle Width="150px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Foo." >
                <HeaderStyle Width="250px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemStyle Width="250px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bar." >
                <HeaderStyle Width="350px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemStyle Width="350px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    lorem ipsum blah lah blah lorem ipsum blah lah blah lorem ipsum blah lah blah lorem ipsum blah lah blah lorem ipsum blah lah blah lorem ipsum blah lah blah lorem ipsum blah lah blah lorem ipsum blah lah blah
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gridviewScroll.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            gridviewScroll();
        });

        function gridviewScroll() {
            $('#<%=gvOpportunity.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({
                width: 660,
                height: 200,
                freezesize: 2
            });
        } 
    </script>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Codebehind:

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gvOpportunity.DataSource = new[] {
                new { ID=1,Value="First" },
                new { ID=2,Value="Second" },
                new { ID=3,Value="Third" },
                new { ID=4,Value="Fourth" }
            };
            gvOpportunity.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

You've got postback events on the paging controls; If you're using an updatepanel to do a partial postback, you'd need to re-run any scripts that make changes to stuff inside the update panel.

```
var doStuff = function(){
    //UI enhancements here...
};
//Shorthand for $(document).ready(doStuff);
$(doStuff);
//trigger the function again when an UpdatePanel finishes replacing its contents
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(doStuff);
```